# how to replace multiple inline whitespace in a column pandas

Tags: pandas, replace

I have 10m line table

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Address':['123 street                   city name     country']})
df
```

I want to strip and remove multiple inline whitespace (can be 2-20 whitespace char).

I tried:

```
df['Address'] = re.sub(' +',' ',df['Address'])
df['Address'] = df.Address.replace(' +',' ')
```

but neither work.

I want to end up with `123 street city name country`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.replace(r' +', ' ', regex=True)

# or
# df['Address'] = df['Address'].replace(' +', ' ', regex=True)
```

*NB. the default behavior of `str.replace` is `regex=False`.*

Output:

```
                        Address
0  123 street city name country
```

Comment: setting regex true worked, thanks